# launching desktop application from silverlight browser

Tags: windows, silverlight-4.0

I have developed one web application using silverlight 4.0. Now the requirement is to launch desktop application (could be thrid party or any platform) from the silverlight browser (mostly IE). Moving further I am planning to establish a communication (TCP/MSMQ) channel among them to communicate. The desktop application may or may not be installed at client side.

So is it possible to achive this ?

thanks in advance.... .

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, your app is going to be OOB. If not you are out of luck. If you are building it as OOB then take a look at the http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/107947/How-to-launch-external-application-or-file-from-Si this should give you a good start on how to start an external application.The following link should give you how to do inter process communication. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93246/Silverlight-Interprocess-Communication-from-Silver